# Laravel In Array validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to validate a payment methods field.

Requirement is the field under validation must be of type array (Multiple values allowed) and the items should not be other than the defined option

```
'payment_method' => 'required|array|in:american_express,cash_on_delivery,paypal,paypal_credit_card,visa_master_card'
```

So the user should pass an array of values for e.g

`array('american_express','paypal');`

But should not pass

`array('american_express', 'bank');`

I am unable to find any such method in Laravel 4.1 documentation. Is there any work around for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually extend the Laravel validator and create your own validation rules. In your case you can very easily define your own rule called `in_array` like so:

```
Validator::extend('in_array', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return !array_diff($value, $parameters);
});
```

That will [compute the difference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) between the user input array found in `$value` and the validator array found in `$parameters`. If all `$value` items are found in `$parameters`, the result would be an empty array, which negated `!` will be `true`, meaning the validation passed. Then you can use the rule you already tried, but replace `in` with `in_array` like so:

```
['payment_method' => 'required|array|in_array:american_express,cash_on_delivery,paypal,paypal_credit_card,visa_master_card']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a later version of Laravel (not sure when the feature becomes available - but certainly in 5.2) you can simply do the following:

```
[
    'payment_method' => 'array',
    'payment_method.*' => 'in:american_express,cash_on_delivery,paypal,paypal_credit_card,visa_master_card'
];
```

You check that the `payment_method` itself is an array if you like, and the star wildcard allows you to match against any in the array input.

You might consider putting this into the `rules()` method of a request validator (that you can generate with `php artisan make:request PaymentRequest` as an example.